# Energy density of a universe with inflation

Tags: cosmology, universe, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, cosmological-inflation, dark-energy

What is the function discribing the energy density of the universe including inflation and a dark energy dominated phase?

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Inflation, whether primordial or late-time, is defined by a positive second derivative of the scale factor, $\ddot{a}> 0$. This is referred to as accelerated expansion. From the Friedmann equation, $$\ddot{a} \propto -a(\rho + 3p),$$ the inflationary equation of state is $p < -\rho/3$, where $p$ is the pressure and $\rho$ is the energy density of the cosmological fluid.